# Polygon limit for 3D objects used for Three.js

Tags: reactjs, three.js

We are in the process of developing our first website made using Three.js. It of course uses a collection of 3D models, some of which are fairly busy cityscapes. We made them low poly, and are avoiding animation at this point, but would like to add some moving elements eventually.

My 3D designer is more used to working with objects used in Unity games, and he says that the industry standard is to keep each model below 100K polygons. Is there a similar limit that is typically used for Three.js?

In my mind, the issue should rather be focussed on file size, so we are trying to optimize this of course. I was just wondering if anyone knows whether there are other concerns to take into consideration in terms of poly-count?

Comment: There is no consensus on poly limit. 100k polygons are a decent threshold, but there are too many variables to know for certain. The performance also depends on number of lights, materials used, shadows, # of drawcalls... You should target the oldest device you need to support, and constantly test the performance impact on it.

Comment: @Marquizzo thank you, that is good advice. Will do!